# Yii2, ActiveRecord и наследование таблиц в PostgreSQL

Tags: php, yii2, postgresql, наследование, activerecord

Есть общая таблица `realty`, от нее наследуются таблицы `flat`, `house`, `area`. Ко всем этим таблицам созданы модели `ActiveRecord`. Наследование такое же, как и в БД.

Форма для редактирования данных этих таблиц общая, но некоторые поля отличаются, для этих полей в каждой модели прописаны правила валидации.

Вопрос следующий: Как наиболее правильно вернуть нужный экземпляр модели, если select был выполнен из общей таблицы?
Я понимаю, что это должно происходить примерно так:

1. Получаем элемент из родительской таблицы
2. Определяем таблицу элемента по полю `type`
3. Заменяем объект модели на модель нужной таблицы, делаем `refresh` для получения дополнительных полей.

Вопрос заключается именно в 3 пункте. Как заменить класс модели без костылей?

Comment: Пытался использовать populateRecord, но не получил ожидаемого результата. Видимо, делал что-то неправильно

Comment: `если select был выполнен из общей таблицы?` а зачем делая select из родительской таблицы получать модель(ActiveRecord) не родительского ряда? Такой подход сам по себе костыль) Но если всё же нужно - вы получили данные ряда из таблицы `realty` , установили по полю `type` какой класс ряда ассоциировать с данными: так и сконструируйте новый инстанс известного класса, передав в конструкторе данные! Может быть я не вижу подвоха, потому что не работал с Yii , но поидее все MVC системы с AR подобны)

Comment: Никак не заменить без костылей. Вы хотите конвертировать тип в название класса, можно это делать с любой оберткой но в итоге все равно придётся это сделать либо через таблицу где есть маппинги(фабрику), либо через костыль типа {$modelName}::find если так получится.

Comment: Я по типу знаю модель, из которой нужно забрать данные. Я думал, что я смогу через `populateRecord` забрать данные из нужной модели и вернуть как результат.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Если используется нативное наследование в Postgresql, то в запросе можно склеить с pg_class

```
SELECT p.relname, r.* FROM realty r, pg_class p
```

и по имени определять наследника (модель), вот тут есть хороший пример подобной реализации 
https://github.com/samdark/yii2-cookbook/blob/master/book/ar-single-table-inheritance.md

Comment: Это немного не то, что мне нужно. Я изначально не знаю тип записи. Мне нужно получить всех родителей, а потом обновить данные из других таблиц.

Comment: О_О, средствами Postgresql можно получить  `relname` и дотянуть данные из таблиц расширений https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/9.5/ddl-inherit.html

Comment: Да, но далее я упираюсь в то, что при обертывании данных в модель внутри Yii, последний использует схему родительской таблицы для определения атрибутов. Мой вопрос скорее про это ограничение, а не про получение данных из бд. Но за ссылку спасибо. Она частично решает мой вопрос.